# Passport req.logIn never call serializeUser

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am trying to signUp and login with passport for my project but i am new in passport and i have some isuues, i have a sequelize database that have (name,password,email), when i post /users it it never go to serializeUser and it load forever.

here is my post request for signUp:

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  
  console.log(req.body, 'create new user');
  const user = await User.create(
    { Name: req.body.Name, Password: req.body.Password, Email: req.body.Email }
  );
  const userss = await User.findOne({ where: { Email: req.body.Email } });
  console.log(user, userss);

  console.log('1');
  try {
    console.log('inserting');
    await user.save(function(err) {
      console.log(user.dataValues.id);
      req.logIn(user.dataValues.id, function(err) { // here is the problem!
        console.log('logIn');
        console.log('inserted');
        return res.redirect('/');
      });
      console.log('inserted?');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.render('users/new', { user, error: req.flash('error') });
  }
});
```

and here is my passport:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log('serialized1');
    done(null, user);
    console.log('serialized2');
    return;
});

passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
    console.log('here0');
    const user = await User.findByPk(id);
    console.log('here2');
    done(null, user);
    console.log('here4');
});
```

and here is the login rout:

```
router.post('/',
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/sessions',
    failureFlash: true
}),
function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('new user connected');
    socketio.io.sockets.emit('msg', `New user connected: ${req.user}`);
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have both two routes pointing to the same path.

I would recommend updating the login routes path.

```js
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/sessions',
    failureFlash: true
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue described in the title also happens with Passport v0.6.0 due to [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/907) issue in the library. So req.login() silently does nothing, serializeUser() never gets called, and moving back to Passport v0.5.3 solves the issue.